Boost Converter DC-DC MOSFET slow closing
I am experiencing a challenge with the design of a DCDC Boost converter that is intended for gasoline direct injection control.
This DCDC converter is configured to generate 65V from a 12V supply, utilizing the NXP PT2001 controller (the MC33816 is quite similar, as the PT2001 manual is currently under NDA).
The controller is set up with a voltage control hysteresis ranging from 65V to 64V. The current flowing through the inductor is maintained between 2-5A (the MOSFET gate toggles on and off) when the voltage drops below 64V. Once the voltage reaches 65V, the control loop pauses until the voltage falls below 64V again.
While the DCDC converter operates effectively under low load conditions, a problem arises under high load scenarios (such as high RPM in the engine, which increases fuel injection within the same timeframe). During these instances, it appears that the MOSFET begins to close very slowly. I have included a picture of the circuit, along with a graph showing the gradual decrease in current as measured at the shunt resistor (10mOhm), and the gate voltage at that moment, measured between the gate resistor (2.2 ohm) and the gate.
Any insights or explanations regarding this phenomenon would be greatly appreciated!

Schematic of circuit (both of the MOSFET has been tested separately with same result)

Voltage at shunt resistor during slow closing/decrease of current

Gate voltage during slow close of MOSFET

Voltage at shunt resistor during normal/correct operation

There may be something lost in translation here; we would normally understand "slow close" as the turn-on time (Vds fall, Id rise). I don't see either measurement indicated in the waveforms. Could you be more specific what your concern is?

I think your FET is turning off correctly (if that's your concern, as @TimWilliams says "slow close" is ambiguous to us).  You have two output caps returning to the top of the sense resistor, so you're measuring the current through them when the FET is off, not just the FET current.  Also, what's the purpose of the 4700 pF cap from gate to source? Seems like it's just adding more work for the driver.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The problem is clear on the DSO. You have 65-20=35V or more than 50% hysteresis, but no error amp is shown.

You need a beefier inductor and run at higher frequency to deliver more current at the output. Obviously inductor current of 2A-5A is insufficient.

It looks like a hysteretic boost CCM converter that varies in decay time with load current, from 832 kHz for a normal load to 23 kHz for a light load.
L= 10 uH and Isense = 10 mohm with 65 mV max = 6.5A max and 20.3 mV min with an expected average of around 40 mV for 4A. The charge time is only 3 us but decay time depends on the load.
The lower hysteresis threshold is not 64 mV but rather 20.3 mV so there is 20/64= 31.7% margin before it goes into DisContinuous  mode (DCM).
If this looks strange to you, say what the design specs are and show the voltage, not just the current and gate voltage..
Watch out for step-down current undershoot.  Step loads will reveal your damping factor from % over/undershoot over a longer period of motion.
No instability was observed with this test.  But if this is supposed to be Voltage regulator with 1V ripple at 65V, you have too much hysteresis.  It looks like a constant current regulator.
Check the manual for the hysteresis settings and slew rate control.
The DSO captures look clean.
To understand it, think of a Schmitt Inverter Relaxation Oscillator with a variable R feedback and L instead of C for reactance.
Yet I don't know your desired \$I_{avg}\$.
